# css change placeholder upon click (without js)

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to implement a text bar. It has to be like this:

[image: My target]

About the language used, you only need to know that it is written from right to left.
The text inside the input element is a placeholder.
When I click in the textbox (not the magnifier icon), it becomes like this:

[image]

Note that the magnifier icon has gone and the whole area is now typable.
I want to implement it using CSS, not javascript. I tried to add svg element of the magnifier to the placeholder attribute of the input but it failed.
For now, I have implemented the second shape (after click) but it is not responsive and does not have the magnifier svg as a place holder.

as a brief explanation of my code, I have one big div for the whole container which is a column flex, one top div where the top header is there and I gave it's down border.
and the input bar. This is what I have implemented:

[image]

by the way, I have access to the svg element:

```
<svg data-v-027aed6c="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1.2em" height="1.2em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="position-absolute search-icon text-steel feather feather-search"><circle data-v-027aed6c="" cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle><line data-v-027aed6c="" x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line></svg>
```

and I can add it to the right of my input textbar, but I don't know how to make it responsive without js.

Comment: Maybe add "- without javascript" to your title to make it absolutely clear (and people don't have to open the question to read the catch in the last line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you are looking for is `:placeholder-shown`. It works with all browsers except Edge before v79, and for IE you can use the prefix form `:-ms-placeholder-shown`. (I'll leave the full styling to you.)

The only thing important to notice here is that in source order the `<svg>` needs to come after the `<input>` element. In RTL writing mode, this might mean you need to reorder the two, for example with the flex `order` property.

```css
span {
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 2em;  
  direction: rtl;
}
input[type="text"] {
  order:2;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
svg {
  order: 1;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: none;
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="text"] + svg * {
    display: none;
}
input[type="text"]:placeholder-shown + svg * {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="text">
  <svg data-v-027aed6c="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1.2em" height="1.2em" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="position-absolute search-icon text-steel feather feather-search">
    <circle data-v-027aed6c="" cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle>
    <line data-v-027aed6c="" x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line>
  </svg>
</span>
```